# Why is this java code not displaying on Eclipse IDE. The public type App must be defined in its own file

Tags: java, class, object

Why is this java code not running?
I am trying to create class and then object from class. 
The code didn't compile, 
It says **The public type App must be defined in its own file **
Pls help.

```
public class Book{
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public int numPages;
}

public class App
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
          Book book1 = new Book();
          book1.title = "Harry Potter";
          book1.author = "JK Rowling";
          book1.numPages = 400;

          System.out.println(book1.title);

          Book book2 = new Book();
          book2.title = "Lord of the Rings";
          book2.author = "JRR Tolkien";
          book2.numPages = 300;

          System.out.println(book2.title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **The public type Book must be defined in its own file** -  java there
  should be a separate file in the project for every public type. So
  you should make another
- Either  you should declare class as  static  class  or should be a separate file
- Already I have included which you have added the Book.class inside
  App.class as static , It will help to you

```java
//The public type Book must be defined in its own file 

//public class Book{
//    public String title;
//    public String author;
//    public int numPages;
//}   

public class App
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
          Book book1 = new Book();
          book1.title = "Harry Potter";
          book1.author = "JK Rowling";
          book1.numPages = 400;

          System.out.println(book1.title);

          Book book2 = new Book();
          book2.title = "Lord of the Rings";
          book2.author = "JRR Tolkien";
          book2.numPages = 300;

          System.out.println(book2.title);
    }
    public static class Book{
        public String title;
        public String author;
        public int numPages;
    }

}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks sir,  I renamed the file to App. java,  now it's working.

Comment: @Laplace125 if this answer worked for you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark at the top left

Comment: OK , it has worked. So sorry I don't know I ought to Check it